# Use of unicode in Django

Tags: python, django

Why is a unicode function required in models.py?

i.e,

```
def __unicode__(self)
    return sumid;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not. If you define a `__unicode__()` method, Django will call it when it needs to render an object in a context where a string representation is needed (e.g. in the model's admin pages).

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) says:

> The `__unicode__()` method is called
>   whenever you call `unicode()` on an
>   object. Since Django's database
>   backends will return Unicode strings
>   in your model's attributes, you would
>   normally want to write a `__unicode__()`
>   method for your model.

Comment: Yeah thanks,,,i am familiar about python and syntax but i am definitely new to django.. Are there any other useful links than the usual django tutorial..Is so please guide me to it........

I got an idea of wht it is...
Thanks for all the replies........

Comment: @Hulk: What's wrong with the Django documentation?  It's excellent.  Some of the best there is.  What's the problem?

Comment: Its a great documentation but the only thing is that beginner does not get much from it......
Lets say for example (pk=1) what shd any one understand from this....

Answer (score 9):

I'm a bit new to Django, but I think I can help you.

First, it isn't exactly required, but it's a really good idea. The field is used to create representations of your objects in the Django admin (otherwise they all have the same name :-P) and when you print out an object to your terminal window to see what's going on (otherwise you get a generic mostly useless message).

Second, from what you wrote, it looks like you're new to Python. I recommend reading some Python tutorials on class syntax. Also, semicolons aren't necessary in this language. The correct syntax for creating the unicode method is:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # Model fields go here

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%i" % self.sumid
```

The `__unicode__` method has double underscores because it is a special function, namely when the builtin function `unicode( obj )` is called on it, it returns a unicode string representation of that object (sort of like java's `ToString`).

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Yeah thanks,,,i am familiar about python and syntax but i am definitely new to django.. Are there any other useful links than the usual django tutorial..Is so please guide me to it........ I got an idea of wht it is... Thanks for all the replies........

Comment: I wish I could point you to some other sources, but so far all I get is random blogs when I google error messages and such. I find the documentation is usually pretty good, you just have to run into a problem framed in the right way to get at why they did certain things.

Comment: `sumid` seems to be undefined. Maybe you want to change it to `self.sumid`?

Answer (score 5):

I think the others have given some detailed explanations that should be more than enough for you. But here's a straightforward answer: `__unicode__()` is equivalent to `toString()` in Java (and many other languages)